# Ubuntu 20.04 - Terminus font not working anymore

Tags: gnome-terminal, fonts, 20.04

I've been using the terminus font from the "xfonts-terminus" package with the default GNOME-terminal. 
Now I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and the font is gone in GNOME-terminal and the Gnome fonts app.

What on earth is going on? How do I get the font back?

Comment: "Now I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04" – From which version, i.e. in which Ubuntu did it work for you?

Comment: Can't you select it in the preferences for your profile in `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: Sorry - it was an upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04
 
No, I cannot select it in the preferences.

Answer (score 6):

Pango stopped supporting old `x11` fonts between versions `1.43` and `1.44`, breaking them for all gtk apps.

Comment: Ah, I understand. That must be the reason, thank you!

Comment: That's sad... There were a reason for fixed size fonts (such as Terminus), to have a perfect rendering.

Comment: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pango/-/issues/386

Answer (score 4):

It looks like 20.04 now has more than one package for Terminus.

- `xfonts-terminus` - Installs the "Terminus" font. Only some applications seem to support it. (eg: Shows up in Konsole, but not Terminator.)
- `fonts-terminus` - Installs the "Terminus (TTF)" font. This seems to work everywhere.

Comment: Too bad Terminus in size 8 now has aliasing. I liked its fuzzilessness at that size.